# apex_item example select list lov

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

Currenly i am working with 3 apex items in same region.

```
1. chckbox
2. selectlist
3. text area 

select apex_item.checkbox(3,ID) select_Checkbox,
       REQUESTED_WORDS,
       apex_item.textarea(10) as Comments,
       APEX_ITEM.SELECT_LIST_FROM_LOV(43,Null,'SELECT_LIST_LOV','%','NO') as Word_Status,
       REQUESTED_BY,
       REQUESTED_DATE
from xo_requests
```

Created one LoV and using that here, my problem is while inserting the record for the checked one in process code every time null value is inserting.

code:

```
begin    
  FOR i in 1..APEX_APPLICATION.G_f06.COUNT LOOP
    apex_application.g_print_success_message :=APEX_APPLICATION.G_f48(i);

    select REQUESTED_WORDS, 
           REQUESTED_BY,
           ID 
      into l_words,
           l_requested_by,
           l_seq_id
      from XO_REQUESTS 
      where ID = APEX_APPLICATION.G_f06(i);

    update XO_REQUESTS set 
      REQUEST_STATUS = APEX_APPLICATION.G_f48(i),
      UPDATED_BY = :APP_USER,
      UPDATED_DATE = SYSDATE
      WHERE ID = l_seq_id 
       and REQUEST_TYPE = 'Add' ;

    insert into XO_REQUEST_HISTORY 
      (ID, REQUEST_ID, ACTION, 
       ACTION_TAKEN_BY, ACTION_TAKEN_DATE, COMMENTS)
    Values
    (XO_REQUEST_HISTORY_SEQ.NEXTVAL, l_seq_id, APEX_APPLICATION.G_f48(i),
     :APP_USER, SYSDATE, APEX_APPLICATION.G_f09(i));

  end loop;        
end;
```

Why is it inserting null value into table?

Please check my code and let me know how to proceed further.

Thanks

Comment: Not entirely clear what `select apex_item.checkbox(3,ID) Select_Checkbox,REQUESTED_WORDS,apex_item.textarea(10) as Comments,APEX_ITEM.SELECT_LIST_FROM_LOV(43,Null,'SELECT_LIST_LOV','%','NO') as Word_Status,REQUESTED_BY,REQUESTED_DATE
from xo_requests` is being done for which apex item, and what item you have the LOV set for, and where is your code placed; as a process for page submit?  Can you format what you are doing for each item separately?

Comment: Your example looks meaningless. You create items with indexes 3, 10, 43 in the SQL query, but use items with indexes 6, 9, 48 in the process.